# cucumber-Junit Assertion fails - It's not able to assert '£' sybmol

Tags: java, selenium, junit, cucumber, assertions

I wrote one cucumber feature which navigates to a site, searches some phones & validates price of phones from the result set. However, the assert fails with the following error message:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: Price is incorrect expected: < ?508.00> but was:<£508.00>
```

Could you help me fix it?

I'm using the following libraries:

```
junit-4.11
cucumber-core-1.1.5
cucumber-html-0.2.3
cucumber-java-1.1.5
cucumber-junit-1.1.5
cucumber-jvm-deps-1.0.3
gherkin-2.12.1
hamcrest-all-1.3
selenium-server-standalone-2.43.1
```

Feature file:

```
Feature: **** 
    phone search and price check feature

Scenario: 

Given I am on  ****** site
When I search for an iPhone
Then I should see the results showing phones at correct prices
  | Results | Price    |
  | record1 | £508.00 |
  | record2 | £415.00 |
  | record3 | £364.99 |
  | record4 | £418.00 |
  | record5 | £421.00 |
```

Extracts from StepDefinition file:

```
.......

@Then("^I should see the results showing phones at correct prices$")
public void validateTheResults(DataTable table) throws Throwable {

    List<List<String>> data = table.raw();

    price = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li[@id='result_0']/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/a/span")).getText();
    System.out.print("Price1 = " +price);
    assertEquals("Price is incorrect",data.get(1).get(1),price); 
    .........
```

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that you're getting a character set mismatch. The [Cucumber troubleshooting guide](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/Troubleshooting) notes several steps to take. Here are two that may be most relevant to your situation:

1. Make sure your `.feature` file is saved as UTF-8
2. Add `require 'cucumber/formatter/unicode'` to your `env.rb` file